# Is there a way to attach "docstrings" to Pandas columns to show when mouse is hovered over?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way that I can add a docstring to a Pandas DataFrame column? I'd like it if I could hover my mouse over column headers on DataFrame in a Jupyter notebook and see a string describing what the column is/means.

[image: DataFrame]

Answer (score 3):

With the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library, we can do a little modification of the HTML of the dataframe to add tooltips:

```py
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def tooltip_cols(df, tooltips):
    """
    Given a DataFrame, displays it with the `tooltips` passed, which are
    shown when the column names are hovered over.
    """
    # Get a notebook-friendly HTML of the frame & soupify
    html = df.to_html(notebook=True)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    
    # For each column, add a tooltip
    for col, tip in zip(soup.find("thead").find_all("th")[1:], tooltips):
        col["title"] = tip
    
    # Display the modified HTML
    display(HTML(str(soup)))
```

where we reach the header via the first "thead" tag and the headers themselves are the "th" tag elements where we skip the very first one which is for the *name* of the columns. Then adding a tooltip is with the "title" attribute.

Example (mouse is on the rightmost column name here):
[image: img showing the tooltips]

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"item":  {0: "A", 1: "A", 2: "B", 3: "A", 4: "D"},
                   "month": {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1},
                   "sales": {0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 300, 3: 100, 4: 300}})

tooltip_cols(df, tooltips=["first", "second one", "some other"])
```

Comment: That's very nice, I made a [version that supports a dictionary](https://pastebin.com/VsER7J62) (in addition to a list) as input. I thinks it's nice to be able to do something like `tooltip_cols(df, {'col3': 'LAST'})`

Comment: Nice! I cooked up something very similar; glad to see that great minds think alike. Some improvements in my version were to use .attrs as a way of carrying around the docstring, and monkey-patching pandas.DataFrame._repr_html_ so you can just display the df like normal in Jupyter and get the new behavior.

Comment: @KerrickStaley then you might want to share this as a self-answer ;)